# 32-bit VB script can't run directly in 64-bit windows 7

Tags: vbscript, 32bit-64bit

Is there anyway to make \SysWoW64\cscript.exe the default windows 7 64-bit interpreter for VB Script?currently when simply I double click on my VBS, it seems to be run with \System32\cscript.exe and as it is based on 32bit DLL it doesn't run successfully, however when I run it with \SysWoW64\cscript.exe through the command prompt, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change in the properties of the file to run by default with \SysWoW64\cscript.exe

Comment: Thanks, it runs correctly now by double clicking on it, however still I have problem when trying to run the same file with python

Comment: Python has nothing to do with cscript.exe.  It has its own interpreter.